# What is the correct pattern to use when your PartialView wants to include scripts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a bunch of partial views in my MVC 5 application.

They are used from a bunch of different pages. They have dependencies on certain script files.

Putting scripts in partial views appears to be a big no-no, so I've been putting the scripts in the parent pages.

I haven't been able to figure out how to keep my page rendering logic from being dispersed throughout several source files, and it is annoying to be forgetting references on different pages all the time when I add an existing partial view to them.

It seems like some sort of #include directive would be useful in razor partial views. Has someone bolted this on to MVC in a user contrib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [forloop htmlhelpers](https://bitbucket.org/forloop/forloop-htmlhelpers/wiki/Home)...

In global.asax...

```
Forloop.HtmlHelpers.ScriptContext.ScriptPathResolver = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render;
```

In Layout.cshtml...

```
@Html.RenderScripts()
```

In Partial View...

```
@using (var ctx = Html.BeginScriptContext())
{
    ctx.AddScriptFile("~/bundles/whatever");
    ctx.AddScriptBlock(
    @<script>

    </script>
    );
}
```

It'd be nice if this package handled css files also...usually a partial view is using some javascript that also requires some css.

Comment: Yeah css is another place where I have this issue. Though it seems less egregious because most sites just have a giant minimized css file that they serve on every page.